# 404 not found error is being displayed after entering the credentials in Oracle Enterprise manager in Enterprise Manager

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

OS: Red Hat Linux. 
Oracle: 10g

After entering the credentials in the Oracle Enterprise manager, the following error is displayed `404 Not Found`

And after checking the listener status, the following result is shown:

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 13-DEC-2013 11:32:21

Copyright (c) 1991, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                13-DEC-2013 11:32:12
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 8 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/product/10.2.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/product/10.2.0/db_1/network/log/listener.log
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

How to resolve this problem so as to run Oracle Enterprise manager?

Comment: You'd just starred your listener (8s uptime); you need to give any running database(s) time to register. Does `lsnrctl` show services now? Did OEM work after starting the listener? Since the listener was down I guess the server had restarted - did the database start, and did you run `emctl`?

Comment: lsnrctl status is showing UNKNOWN STATUS. After registering it manually, The status is showing READY.
But, running "emctl start dbconsole" command and entering the credentials:
Username: sys
password: xxx
Logging as: sysdba

It is showing the same error.

404 Not found.